# Getting page excerpt by page ID wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I trying to make a shortcode to output specific page excerpt.Did research but there is no output on the code that I structured.

```
function page_shortcode( $atts )
    {
        $page_id = 173;
        $page_data = get_page( $page_id );
        $the_excerpt = $page_data->post_excerpt;


        echo $the_excerpt;

    }

    add_shortcode( 'page_shortcode_excerpt', 'page_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page excerpt activation code is okay! but the get_page function you used in your shortcode is deprecated. you can check here [enter link description here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page/) for more information.

Try putting below code for your shortcode:

```
function page_shortcode( $atts )
{
    $page_id = 173;
    $page_data = get_post( $page_id );
    $the_excerpt = $page_data->post_excerpt;

    return $the_excerpt;
}
add_shortcode( 'page_shortcode_excerpt', 'page_shortcode');
```

Also when you edit the page with id=173 from your admin panel, from screen options check excerpt check box at the top of the page and check if the excerpt field has any value or not. If not excerpt on front end won't show anything.

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to activate excerpt on page using this line of code

```
 add_action( 'init', 'add_excerpts_to_pages' );
function add_excerpts_to_pages() {
     add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
}
```

reference : [excerpt on page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158972/how-to-get-post-or-page-excerpt-using-post-excerpt)